# jQuery scrolling wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scroll

Can't make smooth scrolling on my wordpress site. Without jQuery all fine.

My site http://keramhof.com/#about

My code in header.Alert is work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2    /jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href^="#"]').click(function () { 

    elementClick = $(this).attr("href");      
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(elementClick).offset().top}, 300);
    alert(elementClick);       

  return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

My code on page:

```
<div id="description"><a href = "#text"><img id="down" src="...."/></a></div>
<p id = "text"> .... .... ....</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I thought wordpress is blocking most js because it could be a risk to the users or something

Comment: it's false because alert is work, and other myscripts is work

Comment: jS is work on y site. Don't work just jQuery and google map API. and Work is jQuery alert, but scroll didn't work (

Comment: js is working* jQuery and google maps aren't working* jQuery alert is working*